# Instagram Graph API unusual error during GET request for insights

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to extract instagram insights data to further analyze it locally and store it. For that I generated a system user access_token with the required permissions. Now I am trying to perform a GET request just as described in this documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/insights

For that my call URL looks like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/{instagram-id}/insights?metric=impressions,reach,profile_views&period=day&access_token={system_user_token}
```

This gives following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) The value must be a valid insights metric",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": xxx  }
}
```

Thinking maybe this is due to my system user token not beeing elegible for this call I tried the Graph API explorer in the browser and a generated access token with the needed permissions. I am not quite sure where to go from here. Thank you for your help

I tried different access_tokens generated in the business manager and also generated in the meta for developers website. I tried to use a variety of different metrics described in the documentation. All gave the same output as described above. I also tried different api versions (15.0 and 16.0)

Comment: Funny enough, your requested metrics and the period appear to be a perfect match for the sample request they give in their documentation, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/insights#sample-request (Using `v16.0` there, but I doubt that things were significantly different in v15.) And problems due to missing permissions usually result in completely differently phrased error messages. Not sure what is going on here. Are you able to request each metric individually, _not_ listing several of them on one go?

Comment: I also tried to isolate factors such as follower count, etc. The only potential issue I can think of is that some metrics are only available with a minimum of 100 followers and the Instagram page I am using is almost brand new. However, there are still insight stats such as impressions and reach available in the business suite, so I disregarded that concern.

Comment: So are you able to request these three metrics each on their own, yes or no?

Comment: I am not, sorry that I wasn't clear about that.

Comment: Okay, that at least excludes the possibility that it was perhaps due to some issue like missing URL encoding making it not recognize the comma as separator. Everything looks okay to me here, and it matches the sample from the documentation - so I would consider filing a bug report, and asking them to clarify what is going on. https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/

Comment: So to resolve this thread. I could solve the problem by changing the Instagram id to one of the several other id's one account has. The response body is misleading, but not a particular bug.